# HTML Time Modifications

Tags: javascript, html, time

I'm trying to make a code to display time like on this table

http://www.thegoreancave.com/tmm/days.php

and the month like on this table

http://www.thegoreancave.com/tmm/calendar_20th.php

what I have right now is this, however there is some kinks in it and I dont know how to correct them to make what I am looking for....this is a personal project, and I just dont know what I'm doing wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var y = new Array();
    var minutes = 1350 * 80;
    var hours = minutes * 40;
    var days = hours * 20;
    var years = days * 365;
    var d = new Date();
    var t= d.getTime();
//hours
    var w = Math.round(t/(1349*79*39)%19);
//minutes
    var x = Math.round(t/(1349*79)%39);
//seconds
    var v = Math.round(t/1350%79);
//milliseconds
    var u = Math.round(t%1349);
//days
    var y = Math.round(t/(1350*80*40*20)%365+19);
//years
    var z = Math.round(t/(1350*80*40*20*365)+1970);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = w;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = v;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;   
    x = checkTime(x);
    v = checkTime(v);
    u = checkTime(u);
//redefining days of the year
    var month;
    var time = y;
if (time<0){
    month = "Se'Var";
}else if (time<13){
    month = "Eleventh Month";
}else if (time<43){
    month = "Twelfth Month";
}else if (time<78){
    month = "En'Kara";
}else if (time<108){
    month = "Hesius in Ar";
}else if (time<138){
    month = "Camerius in Ar / Selnar in Ko-ro-ba";
}else if (time<168){
    month = "En'Var";
}else if (time<198){
    month = "Fifth Month";
}else if (time<228){
    month = "Sixth Month";
}else if (time<258){
    month = "Se'Kara";
}else if (time<288){
    month = "Eighth Month";
}else if (time<318){
    month = "Nineth Month";
}else{
    month = "Se'Var";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = month;
var a = document.getElementById("demo");
a.innerHTML=w+":"+x+":"+v+":"+u+"<br>"+month+" of the year "+z+"<br><br>"+Date();
var t = setTimeout(function(){myFunction()},000);
}
//add zero in front of numbers < 10
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my main concerns are trying to get the time layout correct, and as well as the dates correct

Comment: Can u put a demo on jsfiddle.net and indicate exactly what's wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nedeku/NUtrx/